# How to get data from an api which is build with yii framework

Tags: php, yii2

I have a flutter application and its api which i bought from codecanyon.The api of it is built with yii framework.I want to add a simple table (i added it already and named as "location") and there was already a city controller in api...So i added this function

```
public function actionGetLocation(){
      

        $query = new Query;
        $modelResult = $query->select('*')
            ->from('location')
            ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])->all();

        if (!$modelResult) {
            return ['error' => 'Not found'];
        }

        $response['message'] = 'Ok';
        $response['city'] = $modelResult;

        return $response;

     
    }
```

i added new url into url manager as they did

```
[
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'v1/city',
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'GET get-location'               => 'get-location',
           
        
        ],
    ],
```

Controllers are in the same path...
Their all links are working with flutter apps but only some of them works with postman it s n problem for me but the problem is my function doesnt work with both :)
i need to receive this location data with postman
i used similiar link structure as they did
one of their similiar links

```
http://localhost/myAppBackend/api/web/v1/users/login-social
```

```
http://localhost/myAppBackend/api/web/v1/city/get-location
http://localhost/myAppBackend/api/web/v1/city/getlocation
http://localhost/myAppBackend/api/web/v1/get-location
```

by the way there is no problem with database connection cause in my function i tried to return "hello" but it didnt work as well...
i tried with token , without token
Although there are similiar samples in this api my function doesnt response...I try with postman and returns "404 not found" response
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: P.S : Login-social is their link which works